# Inserting a MySqlDateTime value from C# to a MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datetime, datetime-format

I have a C# application which needs to insert the current datetime to a `datetime` field in a MySQL database. How do I accomplish this?

I am using MySQL Connector/NET 6.9.9. Below is what I have tried so far. `data.currentDateTime` is of type `MySqlDateTime`.

The expected result in the database is the correct datetime, however the actual value is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

```
    // Set up data object and add datetime

    MyData data = new MyData();
    data.currentDateTime = new MySqlDateTime(DateTime.Now);

    // Insert into database
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = getMySqlConnection();
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"
            INSERT INTO my_data (`current_datetime`)
            VALUES (@currentDateTime)
        ", conn);

        log.Debug(data.currentDateTime); // correct timestamp

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("currentDateTime", data.currentDateTime);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       // Value in the database is 0000-00-00 00:00:00

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Hnadle exception
    }
```

MyData class:

```
    public class MyData
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public MySqlDateTime currentDateTime { get; set; }
        // Other fields

        public MyData()
        {
            // Empty constructor
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mjwills Ok sorry for the confusion - I have just tried `new MySqlDateTime(DateTime.Now)` and there is no exception, however the value in the database is 0000-00-00 00:00:00. But when printed in C#, the value is the actual datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering a variant of [MySQL bug 91199](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91199).

With the default [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html), MySQL Server will reject the incorrect `MySqlDateTime` that is serialized by Connector/NET with an `Incorrect datetime value` error.

However, if your MySQL Server doesn't have [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) and [strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) enabled, then attempting to insert a `MySqlDateTime` will “succeed” but the inserted value will be `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Since [bug 91119](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91199) has been incorrectly closed as a duplicate, this probably isn't likely to be fixed soon. As a workaround, you could consider switching to [MySqlConnector](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/), an OSS alternative to Connector/NET that fixes this (and many other bugs).

To work around this with MySql.Data, add the underlying `DateTime` as the parameter value, instead of the `MySqlDateTime` object:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("currentDateTime", data.currentDateTime.GetDateTime());
```

Note that this will throw a `MySqlConversionException` if the `MySqlDateTime` can't be converted to a `DateTime`; if this can happen in your code, you'll need to test `data.currentDateTime.IsValidDateTime` and do something else if that is `false`.

Comment: Wow thanks, this was driving me crazy. Is there another workaround besides using MySqlConnector? It depends on .NET 4.5 while we are stuck on 4.0.

Comment: @user2181948 Added a workaround for MySql.Data at the bottom of my answer.